# String contents change while pasing from view to controller Get method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, string, view, controller

In MVC application, I am passing `string taskName = "a#&+"` from UI text box.

In the controller, parameter `taskName` changes to `taskName = "a"`.

On debugging the view, the value of `taskName` is displayed as expected.

But while passing from view to controller, it changes unexpectedly.

Post method is then posting same incorrect string back to UI. How to obtain `taskName = "a#&+"` in the controller GET method?

I am new to MVC. Please let me know, if I can provide further relevant information.

Comment: Is `a#&+` begin added as a route value? If so it will not work because `#` is a fragment identifier (it and anything following it will not be sent to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not exactly sure how you are passing data from a text box on the page to the controller parameter but based on your description it appears that you must be using javascript to get the value of the text box and then attaching it to the url.  In this case you need to encode the value of the of the text box before using it by using the javascript `encodeURIComponent` function.

See this jsfiddle for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/a7ek6whn/

Comment: Yes @kevin, that is how I am doing this. Thank you everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

The characters # and & are reserved characters in a query string, this is why your value is truncated. You need to [`UrlEncode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode(v=vs.110).aspx) your values in order to get the correct string in the Get, before you perform your Get request.